# Cross-fetch - GET returns response with no body

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I am calling the `GET` method using `cross-fetch`. The problem that I encounter is that I receive the response with code 200 but the body is empty. When I go to the console of the browser and open a `Network` tab I can see the result:

[image]

as you can see in the image there is a data in the response. The code that is responsible for hitting the API looks like this:

```
fetch(API_URL + 'load_packages', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
        }
    }).then((response) => {
        console.log('LOAD PACKAGES RESPONSE: ' + JSON.stringify(response))
        proceedLoadResponse(response)
    })
```

The call works because I receive the response with the status code `200`, but there is no body. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

Using of the `response.json()` returns `{}`

Comment: Maybe there is no response coming from the API. Can you put the URL in Postman or other similar apps?

Comment: As you can see on the screenshot there is an response. Postam also dispalys the response

Comment: I dont know if its everyone but I can't see the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to fetch documentation you have to covert response in json form by using `response.json()` to get actual body.

```
fetch(API_URL + 'load_packages', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
        }
    }).then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then((response) => {
        console.log('LOAD PACKAGES RESPONSE: ' + JSON.stringify(response))
        proceedLoadResponse(response)
    })
```

Comment: I will check it within one hour but it seems to be the thing that I was missing

Comment: it helped! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

`response` is the [`Response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) object, which is just a container object that represents the response. Assuming that `cross-fetch` is just a platform-independent implementation of the native `fetch`, to retrieve the JSON from the response, you need to use the [`response.json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response#Methods) method.

Comment: response.json() returns `{}`

Comment: @PatrykJabłoński I don't see that being mentioned in your question.

Comment: I have just updated the question so it would be more clear